# Passing extra request params to model.save() methods is sent via URL query param

Tags: extjs, extjs7

Shouldn't mymodel.save({params: {test: 1}}) inject the "test" property to the POST payload, along with the model properties? the parameter is being sent as query param `?test=1`

Is there any option to define that?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like its working like described in the docs here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.data.operation.Update.html#cfg-params 
But you can achieve it with a proxy hook for example. For a better answer i would like to ask you to share more code.

Comment: Via proxy hook makes sense. Thanks.